# ADB: undo commands

Tags: android, adb

if I gave the command

```
adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support 1
```

how can I now reactivate the previous state? Maybe putting the 0 value instead of 1 in the above command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , you can reactivate previous state using putting 0 and restart the phone.

**adb shell settings put global enable_freeform_support 0**